# Stored procedure freezes calling function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stg_GetFileDetails]
    @file_name AS NVARCHAR(255),
    @remove_dots AS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@remove_dots = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  
            o.r_object_id,
            '' AS [DAP ID],
            p.nhs_patientid AS [MRN],
            p.nhs_firstname AS [First Name],
            p.nhs_surname AS [Surname],
            o.object_name AS [File Name]
        FROM    
            dm_sysobject_s o
        INNER JOIN 
            nhs_instance_audit_s a ON o.r_object_id = a.r_object_id
        INNER JOIN 
            nhs_patient_document_s d ON d.r_object_id = a.dia_edms_document_id
        INNER JOIN 
            nhs_patient_s p ON d.nhs_patdoc_patientid = p.nhs_patientid
        WHERE 
            [dbo].[No_dots_filename](o.object_name) =  @file_name
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  
            o.r_object_id,
            '' AS [DAP ID],
            p.nhs_patientid AS [MRN],
            p.nhs_firstname AS [First Name],
            p.nhs_surname AS [Surname],
            o.object_name AS [File Name]
        FROM    
            dm_sysobject_s o
        INNER JOIN 
            nhs_instance_audit_s a ON o.r_object_id = a.r_object_id
        INNER JOIN 
            nhs_patient_document_s d ON d.r_object_id = a.dia_edms_document_id
        INNER JOIN 
            nhs_patient_s p ON d.nhs_patdoc_patientid = p.nhs_patientid     
        WHERE 
            o.object_name =  @file_name
    END
```

Now this works fine if `@remove_dots` is false, however when it is true it calls the following function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[No_dots_filename]
    (@file_name AS NVARCHAR(255))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @revised_filename AS NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @ext AS NVARCHAR(5)

    IF (LEN(@file_name) > 4)
    BEGIN
        -- see if the extension is a traditional 3 character one
        IF SUBSTRING(@file_name, LEN(@file_name) - 4, 1) = '.'
        BEGIN
            SET @ext = RIGHT(@file_name, 4)
        END
        ELSE            -- otherwise it might be one of the 4 character extensions like .docx
        BEGIN
            SET @ext = RIGHT(@file_name, 5)
        END 

        -- remove dots from the main filename and then replace the extension
        SET @revised_filename = REPLACE(LEFT(@file_name, LEN(@file_name) - LEN(@ext)), '.', '') + @ext
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @revised_filename = @file_name
    END

    RETURN @revised_filename
END
```

The stored procedure freezes, or at least takes so long that it makes no difference.

Any suggestions as to how to code this better?

Answer (score 0):

There are several resources regarding avoiding to have a function on the left side of your `WHERE` condition, exactly because it causes very bad performance.
Your function is being executed against every single row in the whole result set and this is causing your issue.

One of these resources is [Common SQL Server Mistakes – Functions in the WHERE Clause](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2010/10/27/common-sql-server-mistakes-_1320_-functions-in-the-where-clause/).

One way of avoiding this would be converting your function into a `table-valued` one and cross applying with it.